# .which one is the right class name for h1 to use in query selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, queryselector

this is my html and i don't know which className is the right classname for h1 to select with query selector:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between w-100 pt-10 pb-15">
  <h1 class="product-title mb-0 pl-10 order-2 order-sm-1 ml-auto ml-sm-0" itemprop="name">
   Samsung Galexy A70
  </h1>

</div>
```

is this true?

```
var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title mb-0 pl-10 order-2 order-sm-1 ml-auto ml-sm-0');
```

or this one is true?

```
var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Alireza all the ways are true. The best one may be the unique one or the parent class which is pointing out the unique tag.

Here is the product-title let say. product-title class will make you easy to point anyone out to that particular tag. So make selector with those class which is readable and easy to understand.

Also if you will take mb-0 as your selector then it will also affect other tags.

So according to me, the best one is below one. Any way as pointed by @Geetanjali you can select with any class using dot `.`

> var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title');

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select by multiple class name then you need put a dot `.`
Following all are true

```
var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title');

var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title.mb-0');

var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title.mb-0.pl-10');

var a =document.queryselector( 'h1.product-title.mb-0.pl-10.order-2');
```